# Method [guestMiddleware] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Upon uploading my Laravel site to my production server I am getting the error.

```
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 103:
Method [guestMiddleware] does not exist.
```

I'm at a loss as to where to begin debugging the application. On pages that don't require Auth they are loading fine.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

change `$this->guestMiddleware()` to 'guest'

```
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);       
    //You can see the example here https://laravel-china.org/docs/5.3/controllers
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Composer hadn't pulled in the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Hve you defined guestMiddleware ?

Comment: Its just the standard Laravel Auth files and files are exactly the same as dev server which works fine?

Comment: Have you uploaded kerner.php properly ?

Comment: Its just a pull from the git repo. All files exactly the same